# nopCommerce / Logging user in programmatically via API or Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, cordova, http-headers, nopcommerce

I'm trying to get some help with nopCommerce (using 3.2) and how to login/authenticate a user programmatically.  The objective is to log a user in from a PhoneGap-based mobile app.  I'm very weak on security/authentication/etc, so please correct me if I'm not doing it properly, but here's my strategy...

I've duplicated nopCom's Login action in the CustomerController and called it LoginMobile.  To pass the user info, I send the username and password (over SSL) in Base64 encoding then decode it in the controller, and pull out the user and pass.  This works.  The issue I'm having is when I call the *AuthenticationService.SignIn(...,...)* nopCom method, the user is never getting authenticated even though the SignIn method seems to work perfectly.  I'll put the code below, but it's using the same exact calls in the same controller.  Why wouldn't the user get authenticated?

Also, my strategy for logging in the user on the PhoneGap app will be to use an ajax post call with the requisite added info in the headers to pass the user info.  Currently I'm using Fiddler to test this and it seems to be working.

```
    [HttpPost]
public ActionResult LoginM()
{
    var username = "";
    var password = "";
    CustomerLoginResults loginResult = new CustomerLoginResults();
    var authHeader = this.ControllerContext.HttpContext.Request.Headers.Get("Authorization");

    Debug.Print("authHeader >" + authHeader.ToString() + "<");

    if (authHeader.StartsWith("basic", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) &&
        !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(authHeader))
    {
        Debug.Print("authHeader found with basic authentication");

        var authSplit = authHeader.Split(' ');

        if (authSplit[1].Length > 0)
        {
            var rawCredentials = authSplit[1].Trim();
            var encoding = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");
            var credentials = encoding.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(rawCredentials));
            var split = credentials.Split(':');
            username = split[0];
            password = split[1];

            loginResult = _customerRegistrationService.ValidateCustomer(username, password);
            switch (loginResult)
            {
                case CustomerLoginResults.Successful:
                    {
                        var customer = _customerService.GetCustomerByUsername(username);

                        //migrate shopping cart
                        _shoppingCartService.MigrateShoppingCart(
                            _workContext.CurrentCustomer, 
                            customer, 
                            true);

                        //sign in new customer
                        _authenticationService.SignIn(customer, true);

                        //activity log
                        _customerActivityService.InsertActivity("PublicStore.Login", 
                            _localizationService.GetResource("ActivityLog.PublicStore.Login"), 
                            customer);

                        break;
                    }
                default:
                    {
                        break;
                    }

            }
        }

    }
    // Random test code
    return Json(
        new { 
            userguid = "0123456789",
            username = username,
            password = password,
            loginResult = loginResult,
            isAuth = this.ControllerContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated
        });

}
```

Side note... I was trying to follow along with Pluralsight's API course where they go through securing an API with basic authentication using a custom attribute and passing the info via headers.  I was even less successful with that.  While I tried to use the same code as here, I couldn't even get the user to show up as registered.  At least with the controller method, I can get the user to be signed in properly.  Just including this in case someone is trying to sort out a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

My best shot with the information you provide is that you have some problem with cookie handling. SignIn sets a cookie called NOPCOMMERCE.AUTH that needs to be sent again with every request to keep the user authenticated.

My suggestion is to use Fiddler as you're doing now, to check for the presence of this cookie.

1. Does the server send the cookie to the app after a successful login?
2. Does the app send it again to the server for the next request?

The problem, and the solution, is different in both cases.

Kind regards.